# Pyspark - different Python version in workers & driver

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark

I'm working with pyspark in a python3 enviromet. I have a dataframe and I'm trying to split a column of dense vectos to multiple columns values. 
My df is this:

```
df_vector = kmeansModel_2.transform(finalData).select(['scalaredFeatures', 
                                                       'prediction'])
df_vector.show()

+--------------------+----------+
|    scalaredFeatures|prediction|
+--------------------+----------+
|[0.56785108466505...|         0|
|[1.41962771166263...|         0|
|[2.20042295307707...|         0|
|[0.14196277116626...|         0|
|[1.41962771166263...|         0|
+-------------------------------+
```

Well, in order to do my task I'm using the following code:

```
def extract(row):
    return (row.prediction, ) + tuple(row.scalaredFeatures.toArray().tolist())

df = df_vector.rdd.map(extract)toDF(["prediction"])
```

Unfortunately I get an error:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling 
z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.runJob.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: 
Task 0 in stage 52.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 
0.0 in stage 52.0 (TID 434, localhost, executor driver): 
org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent 
call last):
 File "pyspark/worker.py", line 123, in main
("%d.%d" % sys.version_info[:2], version))
Exception: Python in worker has different version 2.7 than that in 
driver 3.6, PySpark cannot run with different minor versions.Please 
check environment variables PYSPARK_PYTHON and PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON 
are correctly set.
```

Is there anybody whom can help me on this task? Thank!

Comment: Could you open `spark-env.sh` file and check that the `PYSPARK_PYTHON` and `PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON` environment variables are correctly set?

Answer (score 5):

If you use PyCharm, you could add PYSPARK_PYTHON and PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON to run/debug configurations.
[image]

Comment: The best and most straight forward solution to this problem

Comment: this is the most correct answer to get over the issue when running unit test cases

Answer (score 0):

1. Check python version on terminal - python --version
2. Get root user privileges. On terminal type - sudo su
3. Write down the root user password
4. Execute this command to switch to python 3.6 -  update-alternatives
   --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3 1
5. Check python version - python --version
6. Done.